# Weak amenability hereditary properties

Tags: banach-algebras, amenability

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a *commutative* weakly amenable Banach algebra and $\mathcal{B}$ be a Banach algebra, let $\theta:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be a continuous homomorphism with dense range; then it is known that $\mathcal{B}$ is weakly amenable (and commutative).

**Now my question**

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a weakly amenable Banach algebra and $\mathcal{B}$ be a Banach algebra, let $\theta:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be a continuous homomorphism with the dense range. Is $\mathcal{B}$ a weakly amenable Banach algebra?

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Didn't we have some version of this question on MO before? In any case, the answer is no: you can have noncommutative WA Banach algebras which quotient onto non-WA Banach algebras

Comment: However, this is not an obvious fact unless one knows the right sources of examples - I will have to refresh my memory and get back to you. I think that one source of counter-examples arises by taking $A= E\hat\otimes E^*$ for certain Banach spaces $E$, with multiplication defined by $(a\otimes\phi)\cdot (b\otimes\psi)= \phi(b) a\otimes\psi$, but I must confess I've forgotten the details at the moment

Comment: Ah yes, this (very natural and good!) question was asked independently https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260170/quotient-of-weak-amenable-banach-algebras

Comment: @Yemon Choi thank you